# How to write trigger to capture Deactivated user Name & Deactivated date when UserA is trying to deactivates the another UserB

Tags: trigger

Can anyone please help me in below query.

I Need to display the error message Deactivated Reason is mandatory on reason field when UserA tries to deactivate UserB and capture the User Name in Deactivatedby filed and Date in Deactivated date filed if the user deactivates the user .
Thank you in Advance..

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to [edit] tyour question to show us what you've tried so far and point out where you're stuck. Otherwise, this is a "do my work for me" request, which is not what this site is about. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof, like triggers) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the likely event you'd rather not use code for this (ease of maintenance comes to mind), there are two places in Setup to look at:

1. Validation rules, for the User object.
2. Flows (or workflow rules if you're feeling particularly old-fashioned).

For (1), your validation rule logic should look something like the following:

```
ISBLANK(Deactivated_Reason__c) && NOT(IsActive)
```

Make sure the error location is pointing at the Deactivated Reason field so that your users know what to fill in.

For (2), start with a record-triggered flow, on the user. You should end up with one "update records" step, and nothing else other than the initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you Stephen Voris,  I am using flow for(2),but i am unable to display the deactivated  User name in "Deactivated By" field. "Deactivated_By__c" is  Hierarchy look up filled on User Object. I was used below formula, in flow to display the Last Modified User Name.$Record__Prior > Last Modified By ID > Full Name   Could you please help me in this. Thank you in Advance. Regards, Vinay

Comment: That's a type mismatch; if you have a lookup field, it's the ID you want in the first place, not the name text. @Vinay